# How do I redefine a named range with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named range called "X" which is 1000 rows and I want to dynamically reduce this to 100.

I tried `Range("X").Resize(100,1)` and also `.Resize(-900,0)` but neither seem to change the size of the named range when I check in excel by selecting the range from the range drop-down menu. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me. `?range("a1:a1000").resize(100,1).address` returns `$A$1:$A$100`

Answer (score 37):

Let's assume you have a named range called "myRange". If you do this:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("myRange")
Debug.Print r.Resize(10, 1).Address
```

What you are saying is: I have this range `r`. Set it to match `myRange` as its initial state. Then resize `r` to something else. What you've done is you've resized `r`, not `myRange`.

To resize a named range, you need to do something like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim nr As Name

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set nr = wb.Names.Item("myRange")

' give an absolute reference:
nr.RefersTo = "=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$9"

' or, resize relative to old reference:
With nr
    .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(100, 1)
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your contributions. Based on your help I was able to put together this code to resize a range and post n rows from an array to it.

```
Sub PostArrayLinesToRange(ByVal rngName As String, ByRef arr As Variant, ByVal r As Long)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nr As Name          'Variable to change named range size definition

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set rng = Range(rngName)

    rng.Clear
    Set nr = wb.Names.item(rngName)
    With nr
        .RefersTo = .RefersToRange.Resize(r, UBound(arr, 2))
    End With
    Set rng = Range(rngName)
    rng = arr
    Erase arr
    Set nr = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```